# Categorical data for binary classification

Tags: classification, python, categorical-data, dataset

ML newbie here. I'm preparing my data for a binary classification to predict whether a person has an account or not. In total I have 8 variables: 2 numeric (age and household size) and 6 categorical. Is it advisable to change my numeric variables, age and household, to categorical — i.e. age brackets — or better to keep them as discrete numeric values?

Thanks for your help and advice :)

Comment: Someone will post an answer or link to an existing answer about why this is a poor approach (you might get to learn of someone named Frank Harrell), but what advantage(s) do you see to binning your numerical variables?

Comment: probably depends on the model you are using.. it might help to prevent overfitting, but you might not know how fine those intervals should be to keep the information

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it, but be careful with the meaning of your content. All data can change from fine-scale (numeric) to coarse-scale (binary) but it will lose some detail.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! As the [closure link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68834/what-is-the-benefit-of-breaking-up-a-continuous-predictor-variable) shows, this sort of approach has major drawbacks.

Comment: this is helpful, thank you!